# send argument to main class by command line with external jar command

Tags: java, linux, parameter-passing, send, mainclass

I run java application in command line linux with  external jar like this :

```
java -cp ".:commons-net-3.6.jar" FtpClass
```

how can I send argument to main class by command line ?

Comment: Have you tried `java -cp ".:commons-net-3.6.jar" FtpClass arg` arg2 ...`

Comment: thank you work it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify arguments after class like this

```
  java -cp ".:commons-net-3.6.jar" FtpClass A B C
```

Assume example

```
public class Example {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The following example shows how a user might run Example.

```
java Example Drink Hot Java
```

output is

```
Drink
Hot
Java
```

Answer (score 1):

if you add this command :

java -cp ".:commons-net-3.6.jar" FtpClass "test1" "test2"

after you can use this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            FtpsTest test = new FtpsTest();

            test.putFile(args[0],args[1]);
        }
```